# Difference between std::adjacent_find() and std::equal() for checking if all elements in vector are equal

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm trying to figure out the difference between:

```
return std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), std::not_equal_to<>()) == v.end();
```

and

```
return std::equal(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), v.begin());
```

The latter is bit shorter, so I'd prefer writing that, only difference I found being it crashes for empty arrays. Speed was about equal.

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number new title. That's probably what you meant.

Answer (score 5):

My immediate advice would be to avoid both of these. Neither does a good job of informing the reader of your intent. I'd probably use something more like this:

```cpp
return std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                   [&](auto const &i) { return i == v.front(); });
```

At least to me, this seems to make the intent much more apparent (which matters a lot more than the number of bytes of source code).

Comment: In theory, this should be cheaper and safer than OP:s second version too. Only one iterator and no risk of dereferencing `end()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Yeah, in theory. In practice, I'd be surprised if it were much faster--but I'll settle for just as fast and more readable.

Comment: ... no risk of doing `end() + 1` if the range is empty I mean...

Comment: I did 100 thousand iterations with a bunch of different string/double vectors, with all equal or one element just a tiny bit off. They all pretty much performed the same.

Comment: I'm making a function out of this, so the clarity of the one-line code itself isn't really important, but so people aren't familiar with `adjacent_find()` and `equal()` in this context?

Comment: @Det: I suppose it depends on what you mean by "in this context". But no I wouldn't consider what they're doing in this case immediately obvious.

Comment: @JerryCoffin in the context of checking if all elements are equal. To me it's all syntactical C++ code that I'm not even bothered memorizing, but I still come across these snippets fairly often, so that's interesting to hear people don't necessarily know what they mean.

Comment: @Det: I think just about any reasonable programmer could figure out what they mean. But with either of yours, I think a reasonable programmer could end up scratching their head for a minute and wondering: "is that what he really meant to do?" Whereas, with `all_of`, at least to me it seems apparent that the result matches the intent.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Never would've guessed.